# JavaFX UI Controls running slow

Tags: raspberry-pi, java-8, javafx-8, java

I'm trying to run javafx8 application on raspberry pi model B. but keyboard input & mouse motions are seems bit slow. as a example I did it with one textfield on raspberry pi. when I typing to textfeild there is a delay. tableview also same. when I click on a raw. there is a delay between mouse click and selection. I read some blogs on internet that oraclejvm's performances are great on raspberry pi. Is it possible to run javafx controls without delay on raspberry pi? I done couple of optimization on raspberry pi. is it problem with javafx8 or raspberry pi performance?

Comment: did you plug your keyboard directly on pi ? cause before I use a USB hub the keyboard delay was extremly long.

Comment: Its not any delay on console. Nor in LXDE. I start my program direct from the 'java -jar myApplication.jar' command. (I installed jdk8 for arm)

Comment: Is the application entirely in English / other Latin language?

Comment: @sillyfly it is completely in English

Comment: Oh, ok. There is a bug with controls displaying certain languages (such as Arabic, Farsi or Hebrew), which makes them very slow. I thought it may be related.

Answer (score 1):

As you are probably aware the pi does not like graphics very much. I have had the same problems (with swing rather than javafx). This can happen for multiple reasons. First check your OS version. I assume that your using raspbian which had a soft float version for a while. The armel version is way slower particularly in these areas. I would run apt-get upgrade and update first and if the problem persisted, download the latest version of the OS. You are correct that oracle jvm performance is quite good on the pi so the issue is likely to do with your particular setup.

Comment: I have already update the os version. but problem is when I add one textfield into the scene & run the jar on pi it seems like response type of typing is slow. but LXDE interface & textfields on its are really fast to respose. I need to know is that a problem with pi perfomrance or jdk8 arm version or if I use alternative board such as banana pi, cubieboard, beagleboard, etc. will javafx works fine? will javafx arm version works with malli-400 gpu?

Comment: I see some minor delay using swing, and my Pi is as fast as it is going to be on raspbian. javafx IS slower. As a last ditch effort I would try overclocking the pi (sudo rasp-config), if that doesn't work a beagle bone would probably be faster. Why are you using javafx in particular?

Comment: thanx for your attention. I'm a java developer over the 2 years. so I'm trying to develop bushiness application in javafx & hope use it's awesome animations & effects.